# How to get return value from if else block

Tags: scala, if-statement

I want to define a val called `Options` using a Map function. `env` is an argument parameter that can either be "dev" or "prod."
I want to be able to access the val outside of if statement. How can I fix this? Here is what I have:

```
val sfOptions = ""
    if (env == "prod") {
      val sfOptions = Map(
        "sfURL" -> "XXX", "sfUser" -> "XXX", "sfRole" -> "XXX", "sfPassword" -> "XXX",
        "sfDatabase" -> "XXX", "sfSchema" -> "XXX", "sfWarehouse" -> "XXX"
      )
    } else if (env == "dev") {
      val sfOptions = Map(
        "sfURL" -> "XXX", "sfUser" -> "XXX", "sfRole" -> "XXX", "sfPassword" -> "XXX",
        "sfDatabase" -> "XXX", "sfSchema" -> "XXX", "sfWarehouse" -> "XXX"
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to assign the value of sfOptions using the result of a match expression. In this case, something like this:

```scala
val sfOptions = env match {
  case "prod" => Map(
        "sfURL" -> "XXX", "sfUser" -> "XXX", "sfRole" -> "XXX", "sfPassword" -> "XXX",
        "sfDatabase" -> "XXX", "sfSchema" -> "XXX", "sfWarehouse" -> "XXX"
      )
  case "dev" => Map(
        "sfURL" -> "XXX", "sfUser" -> "XXX", "sfRole" -> "XXX", "sfPassword" -> "XXX",
        "sfDatabase" -> "XXX", "sfSchema" -> "XXX", "sfWarehouse" -> "XXX"
      )
}
```

Edit: To do this specifically with an if-else statement, take a look at Raman's post. Because every statement in Scala can return a value, whether that be match or if-else, you can use them directly with an assignment operator.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Makes sense. Didn't know I can use match expression in this case.

Comment: Your answer is correct but this can be one way of doing it, OP has specifically asked to do this from if else block please try updating your answer and please try to elaborate more so OP can understand the concept behind when to use what.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer, I would like to add some background and concept scala uses.
So first of all in scala if and else are function not expression hence `if else` also returns value so we can use `if else` something like this.

```
val result: Boolean = if (condition) 
   true 
else 
   false
```

As we can see if condition matches we will have true in result otherwise false.

Mostly it's recommended that for trivial match we should go with if and else not pattern matching. In your case we can go with if and else.

```
val sfOptions : Map[String, String] = if (env == "prod") {
    Map("sfURL" -> "XXX", "sfUser" -> "XXX", "sfRole" -> "XXX", "sfPassword" -> "XXX",
        "sfDatabase" -> "XXX", "sfSchema" -> "XXX", "sfWarehouse" -> "XXX")
    } else {
Map("sfURL" -> "XXX", "sfUser" -> "XXX", "sfRole" -> "XXX", "sfPassword" -> 
     "XXX","sfDatabase" -> "XXX", "sfSchema" -> "XXX", "sfWarehouse" -> "XXX")
    }
```

You need to keep that in mind that both your condition block return the same data type here `Map[String, String]` else you will get the return type as any and then you won't be able to use `val sfOptions` as you want.